# Flask-WTForms error when specifying validator of maximum length

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have had some trouble getting my maximum length validator for a search bar to work with my flask app. I am currently getting an error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Here is my forms.py:

```
    class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    query = StringField('query', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=20)])
    submit = SubmitField('')
```

and my route in routes.py:

```
@app.route('/gsearch', methods=['POST'])
def gsearch():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("retro_games.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE name LIKE ?",
                    ("%"+form.query.data+"%",))
        game = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('gsearch.html', title='Search', game=game)
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: what happens if `if form.validate_on_submit():` turned out to be false? You're not returning anything but `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle when form is not valid,

```
def gsearch():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("retro_games.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE name LIKE ?",
                    ("%"+form.query.data+"%",))
        game = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('gsearch.html', title='Search', game=game)
    # if form is not vaild, handle the logic here
    return {"error": "game not found"}
```

for more info check [FLASK-WTF Validating Forms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#validating-forms)